# Using breaks in Scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph with limits from 2022-05-29 07:00:00 to 2022-05-29 07:00:00 PM on the x axis. Within these limits I would like 1 hour breaks. I am using scale_x_datetime so that I can graph as continuous variable instead of discrete. I created a vector with all breaks called axisorder.

```
c("2022-05-29 07:00:00", "2022-05-29 08:00:00", "2022-05-29 09:00:00", 
"2022-05-29 10:00:00", "2022-05-29 11:00:00", "2022-05-29 12:00:00", 
"2022-05-29 01:00:00", "2022-05-29 02:00:00", "2022-05-29 03:00:00", 
"2022-05-29 04:00:00", "2022-05-29 05:00:00", "2022-05-29 06:00:00", 
"2022-05-29 07:00:00", "2022-05-29 08:00:00")
```

here is my data

```
structure(list(Id = c("user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
"user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
"user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
"user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6"), 
    ActivityHour = structure(c(1653825600, 1653786000, 1653789600, 
    1653793200, 1653796800, 1653800400, 1653804000, 1653807600, 
    1653811200, 1653814800, 1653818400, 1653822000, 1653825600, 
    1653786000, 1653789600, 1653793200, 1653796800, 1653800400, 
    1653804000, 1653807600, 1653811200, 1653814800, 1653818400, 
    1653822000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    TotalIntensity = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 13L, 
    13L, 143L, 20L, 11L, 19L, 54L, 9L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 9L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), AverageIntensity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.466667, 
    0.216667, 0.216667, 2.383333, 0.333333, 0.183333, 0.316667, 
    0.9, 0.15, 0.316667, 0.4, 0.316667, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

and last but not least my graph code

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "axisorder"), limits = c(as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 07:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 07:00:00")) +
  ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6",
          subtitle = "4-12-2016")
```

I just don't understand how to set up scale_x_datetime to have those limits and breaks? My x axis data is already formatted in (posixct.)

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE -- Here is where I am at..

I have converted my df2$ActivityHour to POSIXct

```
1653800400, 1653804000, 1653807600, 1653811200, 1653814800, 1653818400, 
1653822000, 1653825600, 1653786000, 1653789600, 1653793200, 1653796800, 
1653800400, 1653804000, 1653807600, 1653811200, 1653814800, 1653818400, 
1653822000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

I then updated date_breaks = "hour" and changed my limits limits = c(as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 07:00:00"), as.POSIXct("....))

my new plot data looks like this

```
  ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "hour", limits = c(as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 07:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 19:00:00"))) +
  ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6",
          subtitle = "4-12-2016")
```

my plot comes out weird, as if df2$AverageIntensity is not plotting values correctly with $ActivityHour values. For instance, 13:00:00 no longer correlates to averageintensity of .31 INSTEAD there is no data. I understand this is because df2$ActivityHour values after 12:00:00 should be 13:00:00, 14:00:00, 15:00:00, etc. not back to 01:00:00. so I am looking for the quickest way to fix this?

UPDATE2 -- I fixed this with replace function

```
df2$ActivityHour <- replace(df2$ActivityHour,1,"2022-05-29 00:00:00")
```

and then replaced by position for each one.

Syntax: replace(list , position , replacement_value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

Firstly, your `axisorder` is in character format rather than the required POSIXct. Secondly, you have put "axisorder" in quotation marks, so ggplot thinks you want a single break at a location called `"axisorder"`. You don't actually need `axisorder` anyway, since, as Stefan points out, you can use `date_breaks = "hour"`

Thirdly, and most importantly, you need to use 24-hour time formatting, so your second limit should be "2022-05-29 19:00:00". The same is also true for all the times in your data frame. The times after midday require 12 hours added on to them (and the initial value at midnight needs 12 hours removed):

```r
df2$ActivityHour[14:24] <- df2$ActivityHour[14:24] + 12 * 3600
df2$ActivityHour[1] <- df2$ActivityHour[1] - 12 * 3600

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "hour",
                   limits = c(as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 07:00:00"),
                              as.POSIXct("2022-05-29 19:00:00"))) +
  ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6", subtitle = "4-12-2016")
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. Yeah. You are right, Allan. Haven't had a closer at the data but should have realized that from the weird plot. But I would still go for `date_breaks` instead of using a vector of breaks.

Comment: Okay thank you @AllanCameron. I understand the majority of the comments, however what I am missing is the df2$ActivityHour[14:24] <- df2$ActivityHour[14:24] + 12 * 3600. I don't understand you have to add 43,200 to values 1:00PM to 11:00PM? I have already converted to posixct but it still gave me 11:00:00, 12:00:00, 1:00:00, 2:00:00 etc

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 I think there has been a problem with your time conversion, most likely because your original times had "AM" or "PM" at the end. Your PM times have all been converted to AM times, so that 1PM has become 01:00:00 when it should be 13:00:00. Effectively, any time after noon is 12 hours eariler than it should be, so you need to add 12 hours to it (43,200 seconds)

Comment: @AllanCameron Okay I see so you are updating those values in posixct form the seconds from 1970-01-01.  I understand thank you. I ended up just using replace and indexing the specific elements which needed changed in %y-%m-%d $H:%M:%S form so `df2$ActivityHour <- replace(df2$ActivityHour,1,"2022-05-29 00:00:00")` which worked as well. Thanks again!